# Copy duplicate rows from 2 columns Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with 3 columns (A,B,C).

I want to check for duplicates between column A and C
If a cell value in A matches a cell value in C then I want to copy B in that row to another location (let's say column E).

The cells are located in different rows on columns A and C.
The copy from B column needs to be on the same row as the duplicate on A, not on C.

How can I do this with Excel VBA?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try this `=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$1,C1)>0,B1,"")`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use a formula like:

`=IF(COUNTIF(C:C,A1)>0,B1,"")`

It should give you what you want. Put that in column E, and copy it down for what you need.